# Point doesnt work in calculator ASP

Tags: asp.net

i need to make a calculator with ASP for school. But the problem is that the . output isnt working

Here is my code:

```
protected void btn17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtScherm.Text.Contains(",") != true)
        {
            if(txtScherm.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                txtScherm.Text += "0,";
            }
            else
            {
                txtScherm.Text += ",";
            }
        }
    }
```

.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table3" runat="server" Width="274px">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn16" runat="server" Text="0" Height="50" Width="100" OnClick="btn16_Click"/></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn17" runat="server" Text="." Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn18" runat="server" Text="=" Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn19" runat="server" Text="O2" Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `OnClick` attribute on `btn17` is missing:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn17" runat="server" Text="." OnClick="btn17_Click" ... />
```